# App Engine Exception, how to catch in Android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am trying to use App Engine with Google Endpoints and I just saw a strange behavior. If I throw exception by:

```
throw new Exception("MyException");
```

then if I caught it on the android side in `AsyncTask` which is responsible for connect with Endpoint, I simply cannot get a message from it. If I call `e.getMessage()` I got something like that:

```
503 Service Unavailable
[ code: "503",
...
message: "MyException"
]
```

It is a little bit strange. Is anyone met with this behavior? How can I properly throw Exceptions on App Engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is normal and expected.

App Engine only provides HTTP requests to your Android client.  Exceptions are not "thrown" over HTTP requests, you only get HTTP responses.  You will have to catch the exception on the Google App Engine side, and convert it to an appropriate HTTP error response (if you don't catch it, the default handler gives you a 503 response as you see).

On the Android side, you'll have to check for error results.

Comment: Ok, I know you have right but I cannot find any good example how to do this. Could you tell me a little more precise what exactly I need to do on both sides?

Comment: The simplest way for you to proceed is to just change your android code to check the status code of your http request.  If it's 503, then the contents should be the contents of your exception.